# How do you find column sort and type of order in Excel by C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have a table named "Products" (on "Order detail" worksheet). I want to know if whether I can get the column was sorted (in this image is column "Region") and type of order is custom list China, Taiwan.

I find out on the internet the way to Add sort to a table but I can't find the way I need to fix my problem.

I am looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you for your watching. If I have any mistake in grammar or vocabulary, please forgive to me.

[image]

```
void SortTableCustomList()
{            
    Excel.Worksheet esh = oWB.Worksheets["Order detail"];
    MessageBox.Show(esh.ListObjects["Products"].Sort.SortFields.GetType().Name........
}
```

Comment: First rule: Never empty-catch exception.

Comment: I've just fixed the code

Answer (score 0):

```
//give the value 7 (column "Region")
MessageBox.Show(esh.ListObjects["Products"].Sort.SortFields[1].Key.Column.ToString());
//give the value "xlAscending"
MessageBox.Show(esh.ListObjects["Products"].Sort.SortFields[1].Order.ToString());
```